# BSD 3-Clause License Changed to GNU General Public License v2.0

Tags: relicensing

I had previously downloaded an open source project under the BSD 3-Clause, which I am planning to make use of in a commercial product. As far as I understand, this license will permit this in a closed source operation.

However, the license for the open source project has just changed to GNU General Public License v2.0, which would force me to distribute the source code of my commercial app.

Since I downloaded the source code when the license was BSD 3-Clause, is that the license that applies to my alteration of the code? Or does the new license apply to me, since I don't believe there were any changes to the source code of the original, other than the license change.

Comment: Have you read [Are licenses irrevocable by default](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/4012/458)?

Comment: Just gave that a read over - thank you, it was very helpful.

Comment: Could you bear to edit your question to reflect the query(ies) you have remaining?  Or has the linked question sorted it out for you?

Comment: The linked post has answered the question for me. Is there steps that I can do to report this as "answered"? This is my first question, so sorry for being noob.

Comment: Nope, 'tis done.  Thanks for being responsive - I look forward to reading your second question.