# Will I get copyright strike for Using creative commons video if the license is changed by the owner?

Tags: copyright, creative-commons

Imagine that I used a person's "creative commons" licensed video for making a youtube video and uploaded it to youtube. Then after some time, the person decided to change the video's license from "creative commons" to "Standard Youtube license".

In that scenario, will I get copyright strike for using someones video which is not under cc license?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are licenses irrevocable by default?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/4012/are-licenses-irrevocable-by-default) That covers the legal position; we obviously can't tell you what YouTube will actually do, but if you have any evidence of the video being available under a CC license, ensure you keep a copy.

Comment: you got the license, and you are using the video legally, but that doesn't mean youtube won't ban you because they feel like it